Websocket 192.168.1.202:8000 connection failed over LAN
I have deployed the WhisperFusion package on an RTX 4090 GPU, in which websocket used. I am trying to access the Whisper package via the GPU's IP address and port 8000 from another CPU on the same network, but I am encountering a "websocket connection failed" error.
Someone please help me to resolve this issue to build successfully websocket connection
